# How to filter roles from saving into cookies claim in .NET Core identity

Tags: .net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-identity

I have around 500 roles in my `AspNetRoles` table and I am trying to implement .NET Core identity with cookie authentication. On successful login its setting more number of cookies which causing site not reachable issue.

Here is my configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    }).
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie";
            options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login/Id";
        });

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
```

In my `AccountController` on login, I have this code:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userDetail.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
}
```

The `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` method is taking a lot of time to return the result, I believe it's because of the large number of roles.

Is there any way I can filter out roles before it's setting as claim in the cookie?

Comment: What's your option to achieved now? Modify the role inside the claim when authentication or solve the passwordsignin method?

Comment: Modify the roles inside the claim..If i can filer out the roles before creating the claim , it will automatically solve the passwordsignin waiting issue.

I tried 
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
    {
}
then it was very fast.

Comment: I don't think remove the options will increase the execute speed, these option is just for the new login user and password settings.  I suggest you could write the logging inside the password signin to make sure which part cause the latency.